# Vaadin & Joda DateTime

Tags: datetime, jodatime, vaadin

I use vaadin 6.6 and joda DateTime 1.6.2
I use solution described at [How to use DateField with Joda DateTime property?](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/371184)

Value is set/get correctly, but unfortunatelly I get Conversion exception:

Exception is throw inside BeanValidationValidator:

method is JodaDateTime and value is java.util.Date
JodaTime is not assignable from Date
JodaTime doesn't have String constructor

```
private Object convertValue(Object value)
        throws Property.ConversionException {
    // Try to assign the compatible value directly
    if (value == null
            || method.getType().isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
        return value;
    } else {
        try {
            // Gets the string constructor
            final Constructor constr = method.getType().getConstructor(
                    new Class[] { String.class });

            return constr.newInstance(new Object[] { value.toString() });

        } catch (final java.lang.Exception e) {
            throw new Property.ConversionException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Do you have some ideas???**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but from what I can see in BeanValidationValidator you'd need to extend this as well and add the implicit conversions between JodaTime and java.util.Date.

At least the BeanValidationValidator.validate(Object) method needs to handle this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PopupDateTimeField.java](https://fenix-ashes.ist.utl.pt/open/trunk/vaadin-framework/src/main/java/pt/ist/vaadinframework/ui/fields/PopupDateTimeField.java)
You can also use a PropertyConverter